# Existence of a number field containing $\alpha$ where $p$ is unramified

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I want to better understand the structure of algebraic number fields and for this purpose I am thinking of various problems. One of them I cannot solve, is the following:

Let $p$ be some prime number and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there always some algebraic number field $K$ such that $\alpha$ is in the ring of integers $O_K$ of $K$ and $p$ is unramified in $O_K$, i.e. if $pO_K = \prod_{i=1}^n P_i^{e_i}$ where $P_i$ are different prime ideals of $O_K$, then $e_i = 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: I think you want to say: $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ is integral over $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible. We have:

> Let $L/K/F$ be a tower of number fields and $p \subset F$ a prime. TFAE:
>
> - $p$ is unramified in $L$;
> - $p$ is unramified in $K$ and all primes of $K$ above $p$ are unramified in $L$.

This is a consequence of unique factorization of ideals.

In particular, in the situation of your question, if $p$ is unramified in some field containing $\alpha$ then $p$ is unramified in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. So to give a counterexample, it suffices to give an example of a number field $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and a prime that is ramified in it! Example:

> $\alpha = i$ and $p = 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!